# Why do Group 10 transition metals (and Cu) lose an S electron to fill the D shell?

Tags: electronic-configuration

I don't understand why it varies between Group 10 metals (as with Palladium, Platinum and Darmstadtium) and Copper (Group 11). If each of Palladium, Platinum and Darmstadtium entirely filled the 3d/4d/5d shells then it would make more conceptual sense, but both Platinum and Darmstadtium still have +1/2 spin in the final 4d/5d shell.

Comment: a similar question is here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11069/why-can-cu-have-an-oxidation-number-of-2

Comment: That kind of question comes up regularly but unfortunately there is no easy way to answer it. Have a look at [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/151/189) and [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4332/189) question.

Comment: @Philipp -- that's fine, I'm okay with weird explanations. I'm glad I'm not just missing a fundamental exception to the Aufbau principle. Or is there a rule?

Comment: Well, there is no rule I know of.